axios timeouts without any reason?
I'm trying to use axios to download this file (and headers):
http://daten-hamburg.de/opendata/3d_stadtmodell_lod2/LoD2-DE_HH_2023-04-01.zip
using this getlastModified function:
axiosRetry(axios, {
  retries: 10,
  retryDelay: axiosRetry.exponentialDelay,
  onRetry: (retryCount, error, requestConfig) => {
    log.warn(`Retry attempt #${retryCount} for ${requestConfig.url}`)
  },
})


export const getlastModified = async (url: string) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.head(url, {
      timeout: 20000,
    }) // 20 seconds timeout
    const lastModified = response.headers['last-modified']
    log.debug(response.headers)
    const date = new Date(lastModified)
    return date
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error fetching headers: ${error}`)
    return undefined
  }
}

Strangely, this works on one machine, but not on another even though both have exactly the same axios version and running:
curl -I http://daten-hamburg.de/opendata/3d_stadtmodell_lod2/LoD2-DE_HH_2023-04-01.zip also works on both.
The versions used (from package.json) are:
"axios": "^1.7.7",
"axios-retry": "^4.5.0",

How can I figure out why this times out on one machine (with very fast internet) whilst it does not on the other (which uses a standard cable connection)?
Thanks a lot for ideas,
Cheers
PS: I've found one more thing: I can download the file with curl, but I cannot with wget which hangs when trying to connect to the server. What is going on here?

Could be that this site is trying to reject "bots", and only wants to be accessed by "browsers." See if adding a User-Agent header to your request helps (that is the common, low(est)-level bot detection sites often use in such a scenario.)

copied the header from a chrome request, but had no success. any other idea?

Dunno, maybe it's other headers a browser would send by default - Accept for example.

found the solution: upgrade from node 18 to node 20 on the machine where it did not work. that does not really tell me what the issue is, but at least the code works now :/
